# SwiftUI NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui

Зашел в тупик - нужна помощь!
использую NavigationView и NavigationLink из массива беру данные и создаю NavigationLink, но вот переход должен быть на другой View, не могу понять как это реализовать? Вот пример кодаЖ

```html
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    //@EnvironmentObject var allData: AllData
    let straty = ["TowarView", "TransportPL", "Magazyn", "TransportUA", "MESSENGER", "Ksiegowy", "Pencja", "PencjaPodatki", "Dywydenty", "OtsetkiKredyty", "Lising", "Poczta", "Telefon", "Paliwo", "Utylizacja"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                NavigationLink(destination: TowarView()) {
                                   StratyCategory(name: "TowarView")
                               }
                NavigationLink(destination: TransportPL()) {
                    StratyCategory(name: "TransportPL")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Magazyn()) {
                    StratyCategory(name: "Magazyn")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: TransportUA()) {
                    StratyCategory(name: "TransportUA")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: MESSENGER()) {
                   StratyCategory(name: "MESSENGER")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Ksiegowy()) {
                    StratyCategory(name: "Ksiegowy")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Pencja()) {
                   StratyCategory(name: "Pencja")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: PencjaPodatki()) {
                   StratyCategory(name: "PencjaPodatki")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Dywydenty()) {
                   StratyCategory(name: "Dywydenty")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: OtsetkiKredyty()) {
                   StratyCategory(name: "OtsetkiKredyty")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Lising()) {
                   StratyCategory(name: "Lising")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Poczta()) {
                    StratyCategory(name: "Poczta")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Telefon()) {
                   StratyCategory(name: "Telefon")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Paliwo()) {
                   StratyCategory(name: "Paliwo")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Utylizacja()) {
                    StratyCategory(name: "Utylizacja")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Paliwo()) {
                    StratyCategory(name: "Towar")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct StratyCategory: View{
    var name: String
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            Image(name)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            Text(name)
        }
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В destination нужно передавать имя View.

Comment: Так я и передаю имя, но вот как его передавать через ForEach? Ведь можно не более 10 NavigationLink подряд, а в моем случае больше и код не универсальный, если позже буду добавлять новые View, тогда точно не будет работать

Comment: Нужно передавать some View и знать что оно сразу создается поэтому использовать struct а не var.

Answer (score 0):

Для List в destination нужно передавать всегда один и тот же тип. Таким образом не важно сколько элементов будет в массиве\контейнере(10 или более). Для этого можно воспользоваться type erasure. Соответсвенно, массив должен состоять из элементов одинакового типа и быть Identifiable. Для этого был создан вспомогательный тип данных Content. Пример:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {

    let straty = [
        Container(id: "Tomar", view: AnyView(TowarView())),
        Container(id: "Transport", view: AnyView(TransportPL()))
        // и так далее
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(self.straty) { container in
                NavigationLink(destination: container.view) {
                    StratyCategory(name: container.id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Container: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let view: AnyView
}

struct TowarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("TomarView detail")
    }
}


struct TransportPL: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("TransportPL detail")
    }
}

struct StratyCategory: View {
    var name: String
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            Image(name)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            Text(name)
        }
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь все понял!

Comment: Можно обернуть вьюшки с разными типами в один `Group` тогда не надо будет использовать `AnyView`

Comment: `List(self.straty)` уже deprecated так как имеет ограничения в реактивном мире SwiftUI. Лучше использовать `List` и `ForEach`